# Is it safe to leave MySQL root user without a password if it uses auth_socket?

Tags: passwords, mysql

Since MySQL 5.7, the root user is configured to use the `auth_socket` authentication plugin instead of a password.

Is it safe to leave the root user that way (without a password)?

Comment: Not to sound rude, but that's the whole point of it, isn't it?

Comment: @multithr3at3d I'm not sure I understand, could you elaborate, please? Thanks!

Comment: What @multithr3at3d wants to say is that instead of using a password, it would authenticate you so that you don't have to remember the password and type it over and over.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MySQL socket authentication is a bit different from conventional authentication. Instead of requiring you to type in a password, it simply checks who you are on the system. From the [MySQL developer docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/socket-pluggable-authentication.html):

> As of MySQL 5.5.10, a server-side auth_socket authentication plugin is
>   available that authenticates clients that connect from the local host
>   through the Unix socket file. The plugin uses the SO_PEERCRED socket
>   option to obtain information about the user running the client
>   program.
>
> ...
>
> The socket plugin checks whether the socket user name
>   (the operating system user name) matches the MySQL user name specified
>   by the client program to the server, and permits the connection only
>   if the names match.
>
> Suppose that a MySQL account is created for an operating system user
>   named valerie who is to be authenticated by the auth_socket plugin for
>   connections from the local host through the socket file:

```
CREATE USER 'valerie'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH auth_socket;
```

> If a user on the
>   local host with a login name of stefanie invokes mysql with the option
>   --user=valerie to connect through the socket file, the server uses auth_socket to authenticate the client. The plugin determines that the
>   --user option value (valerie) differs from the client user's name (stephanie) and refuses the connection. If a user named valerie tries
>   the same thing, the plugin finds that the user name and the MySQL user
>   name are both valerie and permits the connection. However, the plugin
>   refuses the connection even for valerie if the connection is made
>   using a different protocol, such as TCP/IP.

To summarize, this protocol assumes that a user who is already logged in to the system should be allowed to log in to the database as that user (assuming that user exists in the database). So, it relies on you having secured the server such that users who are accessing the database should already be trusted.

It also doesn't affect your remote attack surface, as the socket authentication can only be used locally.

TL;DR: as usual, your database's root account will be only as secure as the root account on the system.

Comment: *It also doesn't affect your remote attack surface, as the socket authentication can only be used locally* is pretty important - essentially, it seems socket auth doesn't replace the need for a password at all.

Comment: @HashimAziz that's correct for any users that need remote access, yes, but it does replace e.g. the local root account password.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's completely fine to leave the root user configured to use [`auth_socket`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/socket-pluggable-authentication.html).

To authenticate as a `root` MySQL user who is configured to use the `auth_socket` plugin, you have to be (or `sudo` as) the `root` Unix user on the computer where the MySQL server process is running. But any attacker who gets access to `root` on the computer where MySQL is running is going to be able to compromise your MySQL database *no matter what you do*; for instance, if your `root` MySQL user uses password auth, an attacker with access to the `root` Unix user can just [follow the instructions for resetting the `root` MySQL user's password after forgetting it](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html) and have access anyway.

Given the above, `auth_socket` is probably the most secure auth plugin for the `root` user to use. Configuring a password instead doesn't increase security; instead it *increases the attack surface*, since now anyone who is able to connect to the MySQL server over the network can try to brute-force the `root` MySQL user's password!

I do realise that what I'm saying here seems to contradict [2.9.4 Securing the Initial MySQL Account](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/default-privileges.html), which says:

> Installation of MySQL creates only a `'root'@'localhost'` superuser account that has all privileges and can do anything. If the `root` account has an empty password, your MySQL installation is unprotected: Anyone can connect to the MySQL server as `root` *without a password* and be granted all privileges.

and also the claim at the start of [the password reset instructions I linked above](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html) that:

> If you have never assigned a root password for MySQL, the server does not require a password at all for connecting as `root`. However, this is insecure.

The apparent contradiction is because those docs are written for people who have installed MySQL using the official installers as described at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/installing.html, which *don't* in fact set up the `root` user with the `auth_socket` auth method (even though that would be a good idea!). Since you claim otherwise in your question, I suspect you are installing MySQL from your OS's default package repository instead. This is pretty reasonable - e.g. I'd expect most users of Ubuntu 22.04 will just run `sudo apt install mysql-server` and install from https://packages.ubuntu.com/uk/jammy/amd64/mysql-server instead of following the irritating official setup instructions at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/ - but it means some of the official docs about securing your installation don't apply to you.

If I install MySQL 8.0 from Oracle's official Apt package, by the way, I get *this* screen as part of the installation process, which presumably the question asker here and most readers of this question will never have seen:

[image: Screenshot showing the MySQL installer asking for a password]

The claim in the docs that `root` having no password is "insecure" isn't true if the `root` user uses `auth_socket`, but presumably is or was true of the way some of the official installers set up the `root` user (with a password-based auth method configured but a blank password, so that anybody who can connect on localhost can authenticate as root). If your root user gets created with `auth_socket` auth, though, that's *not* a vulnerability - quite the opposite!